# how can be parallelized this c code using openmp?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, neural-network, openmp, static-code-analysis

This is the c code to edit with openmp instruction to improve the velocity of execution and below the stucture of the file used by the program.
I've try with:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+: hn_out, y_out) private (k,g) shared (y_out_avg, y_exp_avg)
```

but it doesn't work, the expected result is wrong, and different from the serial one. 
I think that there is a logical error in the parallelization, I mean that this algorithm have to be parallelized in another way.

```
// FEEDFORWARD AND BACKPROPAGATION ALGORITHM
// WITH IMPLEMENTAtION OF BATCH TECHNIQUE 
// compute the error in a batch of 5 input and then propagate the error, usefull for the parallelization.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define INPUTN 3        // number of neurons in the input layer
#define HN 3            // number of neurons in the hidden layer
#define OUTN 1          // number of neurons in the output layer
#define DATANUM 1000    // number of training samples
#define EPOCHS 1000
#define BATCH_SIZE 20


typedef struct DataS{
        double input[INPUTN];
        double teach;
}DataS;

int main(){

    double alpha = 0.0000001;       //learning rate
    double hn_out[HN];
    double price_M;
    double y_out = 0.0;
    double error;                   //loss function 
    int k,g;
    double delta_y;
    double delta_w[HN][INPUTN];
    double delta_b[HN];
    DataS data[DATANUM];
    double w[HN][INPUTN];
    double v[HN];
    double b[HN];
    FILE *fp1;
    double relative_err = 0;
    double y_avg = 0.0;
    double y_out_avg = 0.0;
    double y_exp_avg = 0.0;

    //weights initialization
    for(int i=0; i<HN; i++){
        v[i]= 1.0;
        for(int j=0; j<INPUTN; j++)
            w[i][j]= 1.0;
        b[i]=0.0;
    }

    //get Dataset
    fp1 = fopen("Dataset_3.txt", "r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<DATANUM; i++){
        fscanf(fp1, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf", &data[i].input[0], &data[i].input[1], &data[i].input[2], &data[i].teach);
        printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", data[i].input[0], data[i].input[1], data[i].input[2], data[i].teach);
        y_avg += data[i].teach/DATANUM;
    }
    fclose(fp1);

    //START ALGORITHM
    double ti = omp_get_wtime();    //initial time
    for (int i = 0; i < EPOCHS; i ++) {
        printf("\nepoch %d) ", i);
        relative_err=0;
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction (+: hn_out, y_out) private (k,g) shared (y_out_avg, y_exp_avg)
        for(int j=0; j<DATANUM/BATCH_SIZE; j++){
            //FEEDFORWARD
            //compute hn_out[HN]
            int base = j*BATCH_SIZE;
            printf("Avg of data:");
            for(int i_b=0; i_b<BATCH_SIZE; i_b++){
                printf(" %d", base+i_b);
                for(k=0; k<HN; k++){
                    hn_out[k]= 0.0;
                }

                for(k=0; k<HN; k++){
                    for(g=0; g<INPUTN; g++){
                        hn_out[k]+= w[k][g]*data[base+i_b].input[g];
                    }
                    hn_out[k]+= b[k];
                }

                //compute y_out[OUTN]
                y_out= 0.0;             
                for(g=0; g<HN; g++){
                    y_out += hn_out[g]*v[g];
                }
                y_out = y_out/HN;
                y_out_avg += y_out/BATCH_SIZE;
                y_exp_avg += data[base+i_b].teach/BATCH_SIZE;
            } 
            //LOSS FUNCTION
            error = pow((y_out_avg-y_exp_avg),2);
            printf("\nESTIM_AVG\tREAL_AVG\tRELATIVE_ERROR");
            relative_err = fabs((y_out_avg-y_exp_avg)/y_avg);   //relative_error: (prezzo calcolato - prezzo atteso)/misura attesa media
            printf("\n%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", y_out_avg, y_exp_avg, relative_err);

            //BACKPROPAGATION
            //update bias and weight
            for(k=0;k<HN;k++){
                for(g=0; g<INPUTN; g++){
                    w[k][g] = w[k][g]-2*alpha*data[j].input[g]*(y_out_avg-y_exp_avg);
                    v[g]= v[g]-2*alpha*(y_out_avg-y_exp_avg);
                }
                b[k]= b[k]-2*alpha*(y_out_avg-y_exp_avg);
                //b[k]= 0;
            }
            y_out_avg = 0.0;
            y_exp_avg = 0.0;
        }
    }
    double tf = omp_get_wtime();    //final time
    double time = tf - ti;          //effective time for the execution
    printf ("Elapsed time: %lf\n", time);  
    return 0;
}
```

using a file "Dataset_3.txt" which have 1000 rows of data here an example of 10 data:
u can copy and paste and create a file of 1000 rows or edit the code to run it correctly.

```
121.3168139 6.873759459 7   322386.5042
99.60902165 4.63043755  7   284554.0498
135.7221604 6.663354979 4   284796.0999
133.7192657 3.496973506 7   343977.1519
155.0125801 2.259712681 8   390169.2343
152.0527816 3.643403786 4   309419.1429
64.71485146 5.10618215  7   235827.262
130.6841885 5.405015338 4   280079.0986
56.36704    1.557336041 5   193401.2459
96.33489022 2.840480371 4   234694.1379
```

need some help for speed-up the program execution using openmp.

Answer (score 1):

The level at witch you placed you OpenMP directive isn't the right one as there are too many things in the `j` loop that are not meant to be executed in parallel.
However, you can consider parallelizing the `i_b` loop.
For this one, a good stating point for this would be for example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:y_out_avg,y_exp_avg) private(k,g,y_out,hn_out)
```

If/when you're happy with the correctness of the code and if you want to go further in the parallelisation, then you can consider the "BACKPROPAGATION" loops and see what could be done there...